# Find files created within time frame linux find command

Tags: find, redhat-enterprise-linux

This command runs fine - however it takes in a 24 hour block of time since I run the command. So if I run this at 7pm, I get a lot of files from the previous work day starting at 7pm. I tried the *-daystart* command which I am having difficulty integrating it with the pipe to disk usage.

```
find /eqtynas/ -type f -mtime -1 -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=- --total -s > /tmp/24hourUsage.20171101 &
```

Would there be a way to extract just the files created from 7am to 5pm ( a ten hour time frame ) with find ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 find . -type f -newermt "today 7:00:00" ! -newermt "today 17:00:00"
```

Comment: find: invalid predicate `-newermt'

Comment: Then you have a _very old_ version of find. Find has this feature since 2007. It's time to upgrade.

Comment: How do I find out what version of find I have ?